# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, login

Buen día, soy nueva muy nueva en `Flutter` es por eso tanta pregunta, en este momento estoy tratando de cambiar mi login para poder guardar las preferencias del usuario, ya que las necesitare en otra parte de mi código, anteriormente lo había hecho funcionar utilizando `statusCode`, pero ahora necesito guardas las preferencias, me marca un error de que un `List<dynamic>` no es un subtipo de `Map<String, dynamic>`.

> Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

No encuentro cual es mi error, estoy trabajando con un servidor externo, estaba siguiendo un tutorial pero este se conecta con `Firebase`, entonces al intentar hacerlo con el servidor externo ya no pude hacerlo funcionar, la respuesta del servidor no es un token con los datos dentro, es un arreglo de objetos `[{usuario: xxxxx, nombre: xxxxx, idUser: xxxx, agente:xxxxx }]`

user_provider.dart:

```
class UserProvider {
  final _prefs = new UserPreferences();

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> login(String email, String password) async {

    final url =
        'https://ba1118c.online-server.cloud/ejidoverde/precam/login_conf.php';

    final resp = await http.post(

      url,
      body: json.encode({
        'user': email,
        'pword': password + 'w6@W@R',
        'app_log': '1',
        'parents':
            'eXBGRlh6YUdFMHpkaXpTTk51V3J4enpjaVIxRVhFbWRrSks2TSsvWm9RTT0='
      }),

    );


    Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = json.decode(resp.body);

    print(decodedResp);

    if (decodedResp.containsKey(
            'usuario') &&
        decodedResp.containsKey('iduser') &&
        decodedResp.containsKey('nombre') &&
        decodedResp.containsKey('agente')
        ) {

      _prefs.usuario = decodedResp['usuario'];
      _prefs.iduser = decodedResp['iduser'];
      _prefs.agente = decodedResp['agente'];
      _prefs.nombre = decodedResp['nombre'];


      return {'ok': true, 'usuario': decodedResp['usuario']};
    } else {
      return {'ok': false, 'mensaje': decodedResp['error']['message']};
    }
  }
}
```

login_page.dart:

```
_login(LoginBloc bloc, BuildContext context) async {
    Map info = await userProvider.login(bloc.email, bloc.password);

    if (info['ok']) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');
    } else {
      viewAlert(context, 'Información incorrecta');
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, el código agrégalo como texto. PD: seguramente el error ocurre cuando haces `json.decode`, del cual ahora obtienes un `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

Comment: Y como podría resolverlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Opción 1:

Modificar el archivo `login_conf.php` para que devuelva un `JSON` de un objeto (*en `PHP` también podría ser arreglo/matriz asociativo*).
Ejemplo:

```
{usuario: xxxxx, nombre: xxxxx, idUser: xxxx, agente:xxxxx }
```

---

#### Opción 2:

Al cambiar el formato del `JSON`:

- Antes recibía de un objeto (eg: `Map<String, dynamic>`)
- Ahora recibe un arreglo de objetos (eg: `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`)

Para que continué funcionando, necesitas realizar 2 simples modificaciones en el método `login` de la clase `UserProvider`:

- Definir correctamente el tipo de dato que devuelve `json.decode`
- Obtener el primer objeto en la lista, el cual tiene la información que necesitas.

Ejemplo:

```
// ... código anterior
List<Map<String, dynamic>> resp = json.decode(resp.body); // Corregimos el tipo de dato
Map<String, dynamic> decodedResp = resp.first; // 1er elemento en la lista
// ... resto del código
```

---

Referencias:

- [List (class) - Dart manual](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List-class.html)

Comment: La opción 2 no es muy conveniente, ya que si el `login` da error la respuesta también debería ser un arreglo y eso implica que tendrías que modificar el `PHP`.

Comment: Mil gracias intente con las dos, ingrese al objeto que esta dentro del array y así fue más fácil acceder a los datos, del servidor me enviaban un objeto pero la respuesta llegaba dentro de un array, tu respuesta me dio como resolverlo pude ingresar al objeto y así fue más fácil acceder a los datos gracias.